# Range of a convergent sequence is bounded.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

We were given this exercise in class with the solution but some things about it are unclear for me.

> Assume that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges. Show that the set $\{a_n |
> > n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded.
>
> The solution goes as follows.
>
> Since $(a_n)$ converges, there is a number $L$ such that
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L$. By definition, for $\epsilon=1$ we
>   can find $n_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>
> $$n\gt n_{\epsilon} \Rightarrow |a_n-L|\lt\epsilon \Rightarrow
> > |a_n|-|L|\lt\epsilon \Rightarrow |a_n|\lt 1+|L|$$
>
> and by the definition of absolute value
>
> $$-1-|L|\lt a_n\lt 1+|L|.$$
>
> We have found an index of the sequence from which onward its members
>   are bounded from below by $-1-|L|$ and above by $1+|L|$.
>
> Now we can choose $M=max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,|a_2|,...,|a_{n_{\epsilon}}|,
> > 1+|L|\}$ to bound all members of the sequence. Now $|a_n|\lt M$ for
>   all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ hence the set $\{a_n | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is
>   bounded.

The solution makes sense to me until the $M=max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,|a_2|,...,|a_{n_{\epsilon}}|,
> 1+|L|\}$ part. Didn't we already prove the set was bounded by $-1-|L|$ and $1+|L|$ so why was this necessary? I also don't understand the phrase "we have found an index of the sequence from which onward its members are bounded -". Didn't we prove that the whole sequence was bounded?

Comment: You may found the proof in any text of sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have that $|a_n|\leq 1+L$ only if $n>n_\varepsilon $. So, if you set $M=\max\{|a_0|,...,|a_{n_\varepsilon }|, 1+L\}$, then obviously $|a_n|\leq M$ for all $n$.